# Android Media Player Replay Option

Tags: android

How can i replay a .mp3 in my app? I can't replay the mp3 using the start method

Here is the code segment :

```
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    Button myButtonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.songon);
    myButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                    mMediaPlayer.start();

        }
    });


    Button myButtonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.songoff);
    myButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                //mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            }

        }
    });
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replay the mp3 why do `release` and set to `null` your media player?

I guess that is your problem!

Just stop and start it again without releasing your media player instance.

Answer (score 1):

To replay mp3 track try this:

```
private void playSong(int songIndex) {
        // Play song
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Or without calling reset():

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Comment: why do a reset if we want to play the same song again?

Comment: When you call mediaPlayer.reset() mediaPlayer goes to IDLE state. For playback, you should do initialize to prepare before start.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: i don't think there is even a need for `reset` since we are playing the same song again.

Comment: mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping(boolean)